# Finding Orthogonal Trajectories

Tags: integration

Question states:

Describe the orthogonal trajectories for the family of curves given by $y=\frac{C}{x}$ for $C \neq 0$.

The solution to this problem is really simple. We first rewrite the equation as $xy = C$, (2) implicitly differentiate with respect to x, (3) find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, (4) take the negative reciprocal of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (since orthogonal trajectories are perpendicular to each other), (5) separate varialbes and integrate. I didn't show the mathematical steps here because it's really simple. Once you do all that, the solution curves have equation of $$y^2-x^2 = K,$$ where $K$ is a constant.

BUT, while I was first doing this problem, I chose to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of the original equation directly, without rewriting it as $xy = C$ (and thus not using implicit differentiation). Below are my steps (all the variables except $x$ and $y$ - i.e. $A, B, C, D$ - are all constants).

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{C}{x^2}$$
Taking the negative reciprocal, the slope of orthogonal family are
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{C}$$
$$\int C \ dy = \int x^2 \ dx$$
$$Cy = \frac{x^3}{3} + A$$
Multiplying both sides by 3 and having $x$ and $y$ on the same side, we get
$$By-x^3 = D,$$
Where $3C = B$ and $3A = D.$
I tried manipulating the equation $By-x^3 = D$ to fit the solution answer $y^2-x^2 = K,$ but no matter what I do, my first equation doesn't fit the solution answer. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You forgot to eliminate $C$ from $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{C}{x^2}$ using $xy=C$ .

Comment: To Tony Piccolo: No, I do not think that is the problem. using $ xy = C $, we have $ x \frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0 $. Simplifying for $ \frac{dy}{dx}, $ we get  $ \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{y}{x}.$ Taking negative reciprocal, we get the slope of orthogonal family as $\frac{x}{y}$. Then $ \int y \ dy = \int x \ dx $, $ \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C_1$, and thus $y^2 -x^2 = K.$

Comment: My comment is valid if you start from $y=\frac Cx$. So you obtain a differential equation containing $C$ that must be eliminated by $C=xy$ .

Comment: Thanks Piccolo. But why do I have to eliminate $C$ from $ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{C}{x^2} $ ? Why can I not integrate the equation  $-\frac{C}{x^2} $ as it is, with the constant?

Comment: The differential equation of a family of curves must be independent of the parameter defining the family.